# Можно ли ssl для https отключить?

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

Приложение на java. Используется okHttp версии ***2.7.5*** . Делается запрос к другому сервису и вылетает ошибка

```
SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Сертификата у меня нет. Вроде есть решения для версии okHttp3. Но версию поменять не удастся. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Первая же идея - игнорировать сертифика. "okhttp ignore ssl" -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp Отключать - нет нельзя. В даном случае применятся термин "игнорировать ошибку безопасности".

Comment: Этот пост я находил. Там ответ для okHttp3 . Для моей версии нет второго параметра в методе builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
Да и самого билдера нет

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, решение описано здесь  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp .
Как создать второй параметр, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]) , указано выше. 
Вместо builder можете попробовать стандартное из jdk:

```
   public void ignoreCerts() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                }
            }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```